# How to output to the console and file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out a way in python to redirect the script execution log to a file as well as `stdout` in a pythonic way. Is there any easy way of achieving this?

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Comment: on the linux console this is `script | tee logfilename`

Comment: Did you mean something like that?

[Python output buffering][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Comment: Use python logging library!!! its my favorite lib in python :D.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I came up with this [untested]

```
import sys

class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush() # If you want the output to be visible immediately
    def flush(self) :
        for f in self.files:
            f.flush()

f = open('out.txt', 'w')
original = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, f)
print "test"  # This will go to stdout and the file out.txt

#use the original
sys.stdout = original
print "This won't appear on file"  # Only on stdout
f.close()
```

`print>>xyz` in python will expect a `write()` function in `xyz`. You could use your own custom object which has this. Or else, you could also have sys.stdout refer to your object, in which case it will be tee-ed even without `>>xyz`.

Comment: Awesome. This works the way I expected.. since i'm new to programming, trying to understand a bit.. how is the class Tee is called when using the command Tee(sys.stdout,f) as the class def involves only an object (could be a file object) ? please advice

Comment: If you are asking how exactly is `write` invoked.. `print` operations end up as `sys.stdout.write(..)`. Making `sys.stdout` point to an object that has `.write(..)` defined would just fine.

Comment: @Thrustmaster My simpler, but more versatile implementation is http://pastebin.com/7V4AmrUe.  Only difference is that you need to pass in a sequence to the constructor, rather than relying on argument packing, but once it's done, you get easy, and intuitive, access to the tee'd streams.

Comment: please take a look at the standard logging facility in Python 2.7.5 > http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: I find this especially helpful for writing quick LaTeX generators. @Thrustmaster I made another small modification, posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/eacousineau/10427097). Thank you for posting this!

Comment: Useful !
But you may need a flush method in Tee definition
` def flush(self):  for f in self.files:  f.flush() `

Comment: This works great, except when using subprocess. In my main function I do this, then call a function outside main, which calls subprocess, and the output from the subprocess is not written to the file (though it is written to stdout, as normal)

Comment: You should really support all of the methods users would expect to be able to use on sys.stderr or sys.stdout.
For example, don't forget to support isatty().

Comment: Couldn't you restore `sys.stdout` with `sys.__stdout__` instead of saving it out to a variable?

Comment: At the `f.close()` instruction, in the end of my script, I get the following error:



`Exception ignored in: <__main__.Tee object at 0x7f715e77e760>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "constellation_test.py", line 40, in flush
    f.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`


Why?

Comment: @RoadieRich would give an example on how to use your solution? Thanks

Answer (score 66):

Use logging module (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('scope.name')

file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)

stderr_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(stderr_log_handler)

# nice output format
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stderr_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.info('Info message')
logger.error('Error message')
```

Answer (score 13):

I just want to build upon Serpens answer and add the line:

```
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
```

This will allow you to chose what level of message gets logged.

For example in Serpens example,

```
logger.info('Info message')
```

Will not get recorded as it defaults to only recording Warnings and above.

More about levels used can be read about [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels)

Answer (score 8):

**Probably the shortest solution:**

```
def printLog(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    with open('output.out','a') as file:
        print(*args, **kwargs, file=file)

printLog('hello world')
```

Writes 'hello world' to `sys.stdout` and to `output.out` and works exactly the same way as print().

**Note:**
Please do not specify the file argument for the printLog function. Calls like `printLog('test',file='output2.out')` are not supported.

Comment: is there any performance drawbacks? i mean open/close file repeatedly?

Comment: depends on your use case. if you put `printLog` into an often repeated loop this will have strong impact on performance. But putting `print` there is not a good idea, either! What might be an idea is to add some buffer an just write 100 lines at once in the log file. This somehow might be against the idea of your logger

Comment: To specify the filename, just wrap `printLog` with another function that takes a filename: `def print_log(msg, filename):` and inside it define your `printLog` (can name it `_print_log` to indicate privacy), and inside `print_log`, call `_print_log(msg)`. This way your inner function also have access to the `filename` parameter from the outer `print_log` function. So it can use it instead of `output.out`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a small improvement that to @UltraInstinct's Tee class, modified to be a context manager and also captures any exceptions.

```
import traceback
import sys

# Context manager that copies stdout and any exceptions to a log file
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename, 'w')
        self.stdout = sys.stdout

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        if exc_type is not None:
            self.file.write(traceback.format_exc())
        self.file.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)

    def flush(self):
        self.file.flush()
        self.stdout.flush()
```

To use the context manager:

```
print("Print")
with Tee('test.txt'):
    print("Print+Write")
    raise Exception("Test")
print("Print")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `logging` library, which has this capability built in. You simply add handlers to a logger to determine where to send the output.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to redirect the standard output. In your python program file use the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   sys.stdout = open('file.log', 'w')
   #sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
   main()
```

Any std output (e.g. the output of `print 'hi there'`) will be redirected to `file.log` or if you uncomment the second line, any output will just be suppressed.

Comment: This directs the output only to a file.. I want the logs to be displayed both to the file and to the console...

Answer (score 0):

Create an output file and custom function:

```
outputFile = open('outputfile.log', 'w')

def printing(text):
    print(text)
    if outputFile:
        outputFile.write(str(text))
```

Then instead of print(text) in your code, call printing function.

```
printing("START")
printing(datetime.datetime.now())
printing("COMPLETE")
printing(datetime.datetime.now())
```