# Save the output of a cell in iPython notebook?

Tags: save, jupyter-notebook, capture

I have a python loop for in my cell in[16] that calls at every loop a function and that function print a bunch of strings.
Since the number of iterations is big (the notebook file gets to 99+ MB), I would need the output those strings not inside the jupyter file but to a txt or csv file.
I already read the answer mentioned here:
[how to save the output of a cell in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994137/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-cell-in-ipython-notebook)

However, if I use that code I get the following error message in pink:

ERROR:root:Line magic function `%capture` not found (But cell magic `%%capture` exists, did you mean that instead?).

and eventually, also this error message:
NameError: name 'cap' is not defined

So just to give you an example. Let's say I have:

```
def test(i):
    print(i)


for i in range(1,10):
    test(i)
```

How do I export/print out the values from 1 to 10 inside a txt file instead of the notebook?
I'm honestly not a python expert, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Your function def print in first cell...
Then in your second cell this:

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
for i in range(1,5):
test(i)
```

In third cell this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(cap.stdout)
```