# Cell output to PDF -- jupyter. Is that possible?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, report, analytics

I'm wondering if is it possible to generate a pdf file from the output in jupyter notebook. Basically I would like to generate a PDF file based on the cell output.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to save the output of a cell in iPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994137/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-cell-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942111/17713955 check this link. hope it will answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nbconvert package, but (in my opinion) it is a little clunky to configure. I've had a better experience using [Reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/tutorial/).