# Google Colab Cell outputs Can be saved?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Can we save Google Colab Cell outputs along with Notebook for later use?
Any method?

I want to save Colab Notebook along with cell outputs so that I use them later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27994362/12173865

Answer (score 1):

I use version control (git) for most of my projects. So if I want to save the outputs of my Jupyter notebooks at a particular state, I use git to commit the notebook at that particular state, then I could revisit it anytime.

Other ways to save output could be -

1. Saving the cell outputs as strings and then exporting them to text files.
2. If the cell outputs consist of images, I just save the images on my computer.

Comment: I don't use Colab notebooks that much; however, for the non-branded Jupyter ones, the images themselves usually get encoded right in the notebook these days in the base64 format. Saving them separate does save you time extracting later, however.