# Python: stdout to both console and textfile including errors

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to print the output of python to both console and a textfile including errors, if any.

So far my attempts are these:

**Using console:**

```
# mystdout.py
# note that it has missing ) sign
print("hello


# in the terminal:
chmod a+x mystdout.py; ./mystdout.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt
# does not print to oputut.txt if mystout.py has syntax errors
```

**Print to file (python3):**

```
with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:  
    print('hello world', file=f)
    # this does not print to console, only to the file
```

**Defining a class called "Tee"**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author    : Bhishan Poudel
# Date      : Jul 12, 2016


# Imports
import sys
import subprocess

##=============================================================================
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush() 
    def flush(self) :
        for f in self.files:
            f.flush()

f = open('out.txt', 'w')
original = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, f)
##=============================================================================
print('This works good, prints all the output to both console and to a file')
print("This does not print output to file in case of syntax errors")
print("This does not print output of subprocess.call")
```

**Question**
Suppose I have an executable (from C program that prints hello)

```
subprocess.call('./hello')
# How to print output of this executable to both console and outputfile?
```

Note: Code to produce executable hello

```
// gcc -o hello hello.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello\n");
return 0; }
```

Related links:
[How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)
http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/349/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-as-well-as-display-it-out/
[Output on the console and file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325019/output-on-the-console-and-file-using-python)

Comment: Your Python script doesn't have a shebang. How is the system figuring out to have Python execute it?

Comment: @jpmc26, my python script has shebang, at the top of the script, #!/usr/bin/env python   or, should I use: #!/usr/bin/python   ?

Comment: Your example `mystdout.py` script in this question does not have one. The appropriate one to use depends on your environment configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bash (minimum version 4), you can run: `./mystdout |& tee output.txt`. Otherwise your suggestion `./mystdout 2>&1 | tee output.txt` should also work.

Comment: Even when you use `|&`?

Comment: This does not have bash syntax error: chmod a+x mystdout.py; ./mystdout.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt  BUT DOES NOT WORK IN CASE OF ERRROS

Comment: ./mystdout2.py |& tee output.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Comment: I have added the minimum version of bash for `|&`, sorry. Can you edit your question to explain "BUT DOES NOT WORK IN CASE OF ERRORS"? You should show the output that is displayed in your terminal but missing from `output.txt`.

Comment: bash --version   GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13),  Can we make it work for bash 3.2?

Comment: `|&` won't work, but `2>&1 |` should. As asked previously: can you edit your question to explain "BUT DOES NOT WORK IN CASE OF ERRORS"? You should show the output that is displayed in your terminal but missing from `output.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution from @Pierre should work.
Otherwise I would suggest intercept stdout/stderr from external process and use logging with two handlers: one for console, another for specific file.
Here is and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout) of log configuration.

Comment: Important if you're writing "production" code and not just a fast script: this answer is, by far, a better long-term answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bash 3.2.53. Unfortunately the solution by Pierre does not worked for me. And solution referred by grundic was too complicated for me.

So, I came up with the easy solution:
When the python run without errors, This method worked for me:

```
python3 a.py | tee aout.txt

# to test other example
echo hello this is a test | tee hello.txt

# Like this it works for every commands.
```